# create a filtered dropdown list based on other dropdown list in excel

Tags: excel, filter, dropdown

Hello everyone and thank for looking at my problem.

I have an asset list that contains 1000's of items. I want to be able to choose an asset item from a drop down list (so I can display its information on a sheet) but I do not want to scroll through the thousands of items to find it. Each asset has an asset name that is unique (building name - department - major type - minor type - serial number). I would like to have a dropdown list of building names, department names and even major type to start to filter out the items in the list. Sometimes I may not know what building the asset is in or which department it belongs to so I need to be able to see all the assets if nothing is selected in that particular dropdown list.

Here is an example:
Departments (100, 110, 120, 130, ...)
Building (Admn, Lib, mus, class, ...)
Major type (veh, eql, eqs, hvac, ...)
So the asset name would be something like: admn-110-mus-hvac-1234
I would like to have a dropdown list that only shows the assets that meet the criteria of the filled out dropdown list.

I have tried using the filter function as well as dependent dropdown list but I have not been successful yet. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: There are a lot of answers on SO regarding dependant dropdown lists. What were your problems?

Comment: I have created the drop down list with the departments, buildings, major types but I have not been able to create the filtered dropdown list from the selected items.

Answer (score 0):

So after more testing and manipulating, I was able to come up with this formula:

=FILTER(E39#,LEFT(C37,SEARCH(" -",E39,1)-1)=LEFT(E39#,SEARCH(" -",E39,1)-1),"empty")

to create a list of filtered assets that is based on the dropdown items selected. This is just for one of the dropdown list items but I should be able to expand it to the other dropdown lists as well.